# How to toggle specific item in list get from firetstore in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, toggle

I am building chat app with firestore in flutter.
I wanted to check spelling when the small button next to the message is tapped. It worked but when I send the new message, the same index message is toggled.
How can I fix this? Or anyone know what keyword should I search to find the solution?
[When I send the first message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxGMA.jpg)
[When I send the second message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUAJp.jpg)

Here is my code.

```dart
  ChatScreen(
    String id, {
    super.key,
    required this.name,
    required this.imgUrl,
    required this.uid,
  })  : docId = id,
        _messagesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('chats')
            .doc(id)
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy("created", descending: true)
            .withConverter<MessageModel>(
              fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) =>
                  MessageModel.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
              toFirestore: (message, _) => message.toJson(),
            );
```

```dart
  return ListView.separated(
                          reverse: true,
                          controller: _scrollController,
                          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final MessageModel message =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();

                            final Message messageWidget = Message(
                              content: message.content,
                              created: message.created,
                              type: message.type,
                              isMine: message.sender ==
                                  FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
                              correctSpellModel: message.corrected,
                            );
```

I implemented toggle inside the message components.

If there is no other way then, Im gonna save the toggle statement to firestore ...